# Nuxt3 router doesn't push user to certain page

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have two middlewares:

1. Login page middleware pushes logged in user to his maximum's role allowed dashboard (example: user, owner -> owner / user -> user)
2. Panel middleware checks user roles and if there's no permission to visit the page it redirects back to login (worker will be redirected to login page if he tries to watch owner dashboard)

To make logout function I created query path in the first middleware (login?logout=true) and when user wants to logout, dashboard should redirect him to login page with this query, though it doesn't

The thing is that when I do redirection, console.log(to) method on the first middleware prints me:

> fullPath: "/dashboard/owner"

Redirect method

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'login', query: { 'logout': true } })
```

First middleware

```
import { authoritiesRoutes } from "~~/middleware/panel"
import { useAuthStore } from "~~/store/auth"

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async ({ $pinia }, to, from) => {
    const token = useCookie('accessToken')
    console.log(to)

    if (to.query.logout === 'true') {
        token.value = null
        return navigateTo('/login')
    }

    if (token.value) {
        const store = useAuthStore($pinia)
        await store.retrieveUser(token.value)
        if (store.user != null) {
            const permissionLevel = store.getUser.authorities.length
            const routeName = authoritiesRoutes[permissionLevel]
            const route = '/' + routeName.replace('-', '/')
            return route;
        }
    }
})
```

Second middleware

```
import { useAuthStore } from '~~/store/auth'

export enum authoritiesRoutes {
    'panel' = 1,
    'dashboard' = 2,
    'dashboard-owner' = 3
}

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async ({ $pinia, $event }, to) => {
    const token = useCookie('accessToken')

    if (!token.value) {
        return navigateTo('/login')
    }

    const store = useAuthStore($pinia)
    await store.retrieveUser(token.value)

    if (store.user == null) {
        return navigateTo('/login')
    }

    const permissionLevel = authoritiesRoutes[to.name];
    if (store.getUser.authorities.length < permissionLevel) {
        return navigateTo("/login?error=you%20don't%20have%20permission%20to%20watch%20this%20page")
    }
})
```

Comment: Any error? Are the middlewares properly running (tried a `console.log` in it)?

Comment: @kissu There's no error, but when I used console.log(to) on my first middleware it printed me object with `fullPath: "/dashboard/owner"` though I guess it should've print me `fullPath: "/login?logout=true"`

Comment: What are those? Is the second one the page you're meant to go?

Comment: @kissu In the panel I created logout button which should redirect user to `login?logout=true` page and the first middleware should detect `logout=true` query, clear accessToken cookie and redirect user to login page, the problem is to variable should print the page where user gets redirected and when user clicks the button it shows a page where this button is executed. I can't figure out why and what to do

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that `(async ({ $pinia }, to, from)` in the middlewares should be `(async (to, { $pinia })`
I also found out that useCookie method works only when page is reloaded so I did my task this way:

1. First middleware

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, { $pinia }) => {
    var token = useCookie('accessToken')
    const store = useAuthStore($pinia)

    if (to.query.logout === 'true') {
        if (!token.value) {
            return navigateTo('/login')
        }
        token.value = null
        if (process.client) {
            store.logout()
        }
    }

    if (token.value) {
        await store.retrieveUser(token.value)
        if (store.user != null) {
            const permissionLevel = store.getUser.authorities.length
            const routeName = authoritiesRoutes[permissionLevel]
            const route = '/' + routeName.replace('-', '/')
            return route;
        }
    }
})
```

2. Second middleware stays the same
3. Login.vue now has created method that looks like this:

```
created () {
      if (this.$route.query.logout == 'true') {
        this.$router.go(0)
      }
    }
```